# Repairing dimmer switch

Tags: repair, dimmer-switch

I have an IKEA lamp with dimmer switch which took a knock and immediately started outputting full brightness. I've read a little about how dimmer switches work and that this is likely caused by the triac breaking.

I would like to repair this by replacing the triac (/diac combination?) but want to make sure that I have the right idea and check if there are any risks in doing so.

Photos:

[image: Top front]
[image: Top back]
[image: Bottom]

As I understand it the block in the middle with the metal cover is the triac, possible also a unit containing a diac. Then the obvious variable resistor connected to the outside, a fuse (looks like a second fuse attached under the metal hood -- and labelled on the board -- but can't see it properly until disassembly), some resistors (baseline resistance? "taper"?) and finally the inductor and capacitor smooth out the voltage cut, reducing stress/noise on/from the load.

I plan to desolder the triac unit and replace it with an equivalent part (if I can find one). Is there a good way to confirm the triac is broken in advance? Are there any safety concerns?

Comment: You should just buy a whole new device.  These things are not serviceable,  and could be a hazard if repaired incorrectly.

Comment: have you tried http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Paul I couldn't decide between DIY and Electronics. In the end this seemed more appropriate.

Comment: @Tester101 can you elaborate on the risks? They must already be engineered to deal with triac failure, since these have a tendency to fail, so replacing the triac doesn't seem so risky to me.

Comment: @SamBrightman That device was likely quality control tested by the manufacturer,  and the product line was surely tested by UL or some other body.  Once you poke around, all that safety testing is null and void. If you know what you're doing, and make the repair to manufacturer specifications there's little risk.  Since you're asking this question, it means you don't know what you're doing. If you make a mistake during the repair,  you could introduce a dangerous fault point.  Unless you plan to submit the device for QA testing after the repair, you can't be sure your fix is up to snuff.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I prefer to learn about DIY, including risks and failure modes (units that pass QA also fail, as this one has).

Comment: Hey did you go about this repair and was it successful?

Comment: No, the triac and its metal casing were solidly attached and riveted to the board. The combination of this difficulty and uncertainty about the problem led be to abandon (or at least postpone) this repair. There were some other answers on electronics http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211507/led-circuit-with-epoxy-and-broken-transistor

Comment: Triac or scr you may find with shipping the component cost more than a new one, another possibility is the cheap variable resistor is damaged, this provides the gate voltage for the SCR , most dimmers used to be scr's as they could say you get energy savings because they don't use the full wave form to the load, where a triac is Basicly 2 SCR's back to back that can use the full waveform.

Answer (score 2):

Fuse is "fired" 
Uncover black jacket around "fuse" (first pic.) 
In my dimmer is fuse represented by resistor.
Resistor values are represented by color stripes

https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code-4-band

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/resistors/decoding-resistor-markings

In my dimmer is 
0,29 Ohm +-5% tolerance -> stripes red, white, silver, gold
(or 29G Ohm - 29 000 000 000 Ohm +- 5% tolerance -> red, white, grey, gold - iam not shure in 3rd tripe, but i think that is imposible 29G Ohm in table light dimmer)

Comment: What do you mean by “fired”? If blown, it would be always off not always on.

Answer (score 1):

Since you dropped it, more likely than the triac failing, would be a connection.

The circuit board uses lead-free solder. Lead free solder is brittle breaks often, especially where large components connect to the board. Use basic electronics repair skill to re-solder all the connections and see if it works.

I don't like lead-free solder. Lead is bad, but even worse is the environmental damage caused by equipment getting junked early for lead-free solder problems.

Check the fuse, too. It's a glass tube with a tiny piece of wire suspended through it. Fuses break all the time when you drop electronic equipment.

Comment: Wouldn't these failure modes would much more likely cause no light than full brightness?